# Is it possible to put a render function inside a for loop in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

So i am rendering a webpage after i go through a for loop but the problem is that when i put the render inside the for loop, the same page gets renders multiple times which ends up giving me the error:

```
Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

^^ This crashes my app.

If i put my render outside the for loop, the data that i am pulling cannot be pulled.

```
router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) =>
{
const roomArr = [];

model.findById(req.session.userLogin._id)
.then((user) =>
{

    user.bookedRooms.forEach((eachRoom) =>
    {
        console.log(eachRoom);

        roomModel.findById(eachRoom)
        .then((roomInfo) =>
        {
            console.log(roomInfo);
            console.log(`Rooms Array: ${roomArr}`);
            roomArr.push(roomInfo); 
        })
        .catch((err) =>
        {
            console.log(`Could not book rooms: ${err}`);
        })
    })

    res.render('registration/dashboard', {
        rooms: roomArr,
        ttl: title,
        sty: style
    })

})
```

})

^^ As shown by my code above, my goal is to pull the id of bookedRooms(array) inside my session and then check if that id matches the roomsID in the room collection. If those 2 id's match, that means the user has booked a room.

The problem i am having is that my rooms are not being pulled and i think that might be because my **render** is not after my **.then**.

I guess my main question is does my **render** have to be right after my **.then**??

Comment: user is my database model and bookedRooms is an array inside my mongoDB collection

Comment: You can only call `res.render()` once per request because it sends the response and you only get to send one response per http request.  It looks to me like you need to collect all the data and then call `res.render()` only when you have all the data and have a template that accepts an array of data.

Comment: Well that is what i was doing above, i only missed out the push part. So im collecting all the booked rooms and then pushing them inside the roomArr Array so that the array contains all the booked rooms. Then at the end of the code im doing a render...

Comment: Well, you're not waiting for all the collecting to be done before you call `res.render()` so you call `res.render()` before any of the rooms have been collected.  Anyway, glad JaromandaX showed you how to do it.

Comment: Do you know how i can fix that problem with my code tho? Cuz if i can figure it out using the Array, i can probz check if the room is inside the array and then i can prevent the user for booking the same room multiple times

Comment: You already accepted JaromandaX's answer.  Did that not solve your problem?  `res.render()` has to be after all the `findById()` operations are DONE which JaromandaX's answer shows.  If you have a different problem that you now want to ask, then you should perhaps file a new question.

Comment: true, ill do that if needed but for now im good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `user.bookedRooms` is a regular Javascript array

do as follows

```
router.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => 
    model.findById(req.session.userLogin._id)
    .then(user => Promise.all(user.bookedRooms.map(eachRoom => roomModel.findById(eachRoom))))
    .then(rooms => res.render('registration/dashboard', {
        rooms,
        ttl: title,
        sty: style
    }))
    .catch(err => console.log(`Could not book rooms: ${err}`))
)
```

Explanation:

1. `model.findById(req.session.userLogin._id)` - does what it did before
2. use Promise.all on the array of Promises returned by ...
3. `user.bookedRooms.map` which, for each `eachRoom` returns the promise returned by
4. `roomModel.findById(eachRoom)` ... so far so good?
5. once ALL promises resolve, the result is in `rooms` in the `.then(rooms`
6. `res.render('registration/dashboard',` ... etc, does what you do in your code

I use `rooms` as the name of the result, to shortcut the

```
res.render('registration/dashboard', {
    rooms: roomsArr,
    ttl: title,
    sty: style
})
```

to

```
res.render('registration/dashboard', {
    rooms,
    ttl: title,
    sty: style
})
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203730/discussion-on-answer-by-jaromanda-x-is-it-possible-to-put-a-render-function-insi).

Comment: @SamuelLiew the comments were important to get the answer **RIGHT** though